# Truffle deploy insufficient funds (despite using Truffle's total price estimates)

Tags: truffle, consensys-truffle

**1. Dry run deploy**

```
Migrations dry-run (simulation)
.....
> Total deployments:   2
> Final cost:          0.058258696 ETH
```

That's $83.83

**2. Do I have $83.83? Yes I do.**
[image]

**3. Double check mainNet configs (`truffle-config.js`):**

- Current gas in Gwei 105 (105000000000 Wei)
- Final cost was 0.058258696 ETH (58258696000000000 Wei)

Plug these numbers in:

```
 mainnet: {
      provider: () =>
        new HDWalletProvider({
          mnemonic: { phrase: process.env.MNEMONIC },
          providerOrUrl: process.env.RPC_URL_1,
        }),
      network_id: 1,
      from: process.env.DEPLOYERS_ADDRESS,
      gas: 58258696000000000, 
      gasPrice: 105000000000,
      confirmations: 2, 
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: false, 
    },
```

**4. Time to deploy**

`truffle migrate --network mainnet`

---

Result:

```
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" could not deploy due to insufficient funds
```

---

So, I've...

1. Run the dry run, gotten the estimate cost of deploying the contract. Plugged that value in.
2. Got the current cost of Gas. Plugged that in.
3. Ran the contract
4. The deployment fails

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Your Gas value looks incorrect. Check **Dry Run Output**, you will see `> gas used: 4390736` (example number) or deploy contract to a test network or https://remix.ethereum.org to have an idea of gas used, then update `gas` in `truffle-config.js`